# настройка консоли GitBash

Tags: git, git-bash

есть ли возможность настраивать под себя виндовую консоль GitBash ?

- мне надо изменить дефолтную директорию, куда я попадаю после входа, а то каждый раз приходится писать длинный путь, чтобы попасть в нужно место - где хранятся проекты
- хотелось бы изменить редактор файлов, например с Vim на  nano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

открываете консоль, а дальше делаете так

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

(вместо вима можете запустить свой любимый редактор, файла скорее всего не будет)

в открытом окне редактора вставляете такое

```
cd Documents/myprojects # куда перейти
export EDITOR=nano # а это редактор
```

сохраняете и перезапускаете git bash. Он может ругнуться на то, что отсутствует .bash_profile, но он его создал. Ещё раз закрываем и перезапускаем. Все должно быть так как нужно.

Замечания:

- путь нужно писать по правилам баша, то есть с прямыми слешами
- переменая окружения EDITOR - это такая специальная переменная, куда многие утилиты заглядывают, когда им нужно редактировать файл. В том числе и git, когда ему нужно отредактировать сообщение коммита или сделать интерактивный rebase.
- в этот же файл можно запихнуть и более сложную логику - к примеру, по понедельникам заходить в один каталог, а в другие дни - в другой. Пример

  ```
  if [[ `date "+%u"` == 1 ]] # 1 - понедельник
  then
  cd /tmp
  else
  cd /
  fi
  ```

Comment: круто! сейчас попробую!  
а nano-то откуда возьмется в винде?

Comment: с дефолтным путем - все получилось! спасибо!

Comment: __еще вопрос:__ а как выделять символы в консоли? как в линуксе - не получается :-(

Comment: а как Вы в линуксе выделяете? у меня прекрасно выделяет мышкой и вставляет ею, точно также как в линуксе.

Comment: курсором при нажатой левой клавише выделяю, а потом кликаю, чтобы скопировать...  причем выделяемое видно подсветкой...

Comment: после выделения оно уже копируется в буфер выделения. Так что можно просто кликнуть колесиком и вставить.

Comment: у меня ничего в окне GitBash-консоли не выделяется... возможно только выделение всего правым кликом по рамке окна -> Изменить -> Выделить все...    
по-ходу у меня неправильный ГитБаш :-(

Comment: у Вас просто используется cmd вместо mingw терминала. То есть, в ярлыке должно быть прописано что то вида "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe". Я использую гит с официального сайта и он при установке спрашивает, какой терминал ставить. Вот там как раз и выбирается.

Comment: не понял... а откуда надо скачивать, чтобы не использовать cmd? или что-то где-то надо настраивать? отсюда качать = https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: я ставлю отсюдова https://git-scm.com/downloads , а от github'a у меня нет. По нему не посоветую.

Comment: спасибо за просвещение - консоль переустановил

Comment: при попытке добавить в индекс файл получаю отлуп = CRLF would be replaced by LF in nbproject/project.properties...    
это что и как с этим бороться?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168639/git-commit-get-fatal-error-fatal-crlf-would-be-replaced-by-lf-in

Comment: есть ли возможность где-то посмотреть историю вводившихся в терминале команд? типа bash history?

Comment: ну так команду `history` в баше никто не отменял.